# Echo is showing when it should not be

Tags: php, html

Hello i am having problems with the code below for some reason the echo is showing when i load the file its showing on start up any ideas on how to fix this?

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "<a href='http://$url/files/".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])."'>Download</a>";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999999999999">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Name your submit button `<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">` then wrap your PHP inside `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}`

Comment: *"Thank you! [**it**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791775/echo-is-showing-when-it-should-not-be#comment40339745_25791775) worked :D"* - I gave you the answer above and made it as an answer below, then you accepted someone else's... what's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just make it an answer, see if OP [**accepts it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) to close the question; [`since it did work for OP.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791775/echo-is-showing-when-it-should-not-be/25791931#comment40339832_25791775)

Name your submit button `<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">` then wrap your PHP inside `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}`

---

Another way to do this is to use two seperate files.

For example. HTML form

`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="handler.php" method="POST">...</form>`

**handler.php** (while keeping the named submit button)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "<a href='http://$url/files/".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])."'>Download</a>";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Answer (score 1):

the echo show because you have a if statement and on load page it's always false. put a if with a isset first like this :

```
 if(isset($_POST['uploadedfile'])){
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "<a href='http://$url/files/".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])."'>Download</a>";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
    }
        ?>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999999999999">
        <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
```

Should do the trick if not post more information / code and specifie witch echo is showing... thx

Would be cleaner to add name to the button like name="submit" and do the isset on the button name OR a input type="hidden" with a name for the form.

Answer (score 1):

You never bothered checking if a POST was actually performed, and you also don't bother checking if the upload actually succeeded. **NEVER** assume success. Always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die("Upload failed with error code {$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']}");
   }
   ... do your upload processing here
}
```